# Unable to remove single product pages from woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added the following code snippet to functions.php after reseaching a lot:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

This snippet seems to work for a lot of people. 
I'm using the Salient wordpress theme, and this code snippet has no effect on the hyperlink wrap on single product grids.

Please HELP!

Comment: You should add it to a hook that proceeds when the actions have been set otherwise you won't be able to remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added the snippet you provided into functions.php of the parent theme. 
I am not using a child theme here and want to implement this in the parent theme itself.
The code had no effect on the product links.

Comment: That is not a good idea, any updates to the parent will override your changes.  Use a child theme this is the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to a hook that proceeds when the actions have been set otherwise you won't be able to remove them.  The actions should exist after the 'after_setup_theme' hook.  Also ensure the hooks are removed with the same priority as they were set with.

```
function add_remove_hooks() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
}


add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_remove_hooks' );
```